# Worksheet_Change(Byval Target as Range)

Tags: excel, vba

I know this question has been asked multiple times but I am really struggling to get my head around it and make it work.

I have a spreadsheet with 5 columns on it, 
as in the screenshot below

[ScreenShot of Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pleid.png)

I am trying to populate column "B" with a timestamp when a change occurs in Column "C" and Populate Column "E" with a time stamp when a change occurs in Column "D".

I have the following code so far

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
If Intersect(Target, [C:C]) Is Nothing Or Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Target.Offset(, -1) = Time 
End Sub
```

But no matter what i have tried so far i cannot figure out the code to enable the timestamps to be created independantly within the same Worksheet_Change() sub

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

M